# What are the use cases of sampler2D uniforms in WebGL / OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, webgl

[Samplers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)) goes into a little too much depth without use cases. What are the use cases of sampler2D (texture) uniforms in a vertex shader? Are they used to pass data in ever, or what do you use them for in production games? How creative do people get with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sampler2D is just a way to get data from an array. Don't think of it as a texture. Think of it has a 2D array with special hardware to do interpolation between values in the array (LINEAR filtering) and values between mips. Set the sampling to NEAREST and they just become 2D arrays.

So, your question is about as generic as asking "what are arrays used for in JavaScript". They are used for whatever you want.

Probably the most common thing is [bone matrices for skinned meshes](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-skinning.html). Another example but not nearly as common AFAIK is [having more flexible vertex data at the expense of speed](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-pulling-vertices.html)

But just to re-iterate, texture are just arrays and sampler2D is specifically for 2D arrays so when you need a random access array in a shader use a sampler2D